# Checking for existence of an option with certain text

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm trying to use jQuery to check for the existence of an `<option>` that contains a particular string of text. My attempts so far are not working as I expect. Here's the HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="13">General</option>
    <option value="3">Innovation</option>
    <option value="8">Marketing</option>
    <option value="9">Operations</option>
    <option value="11">Research</option>
</select>
```

Here's the script:

```
var topicSelect = $("select");
var haveTopic = topicSelect.val("Not Here");
alert(haveTopic);
```

I'm expecting the alert to show "undefined" however it seems to be giving back the `select` object. Is there a way I can check for the existence of an option without looping through every one?

Clarifications:

- **string of text** needs to be matched, not value
- looking for an exact, case sensitive match
- can return true/false or undefined

Comment: Do you want the actual `value` of the `option` or the text contents of it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to match -- does it have to completely match? is it a case sensitive match? if the code needs to do a partial match, how do you handle matches that return two different options? and you want it to return `undefined` if no matches are found, true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should find what you're looking for:

```
if ($("option:contains('not here')").length > 1) {  }
```

The reason your original code didn't work is because you were setting the value attribute of the selector, and it was returning the select because jQuery methods will (almost) always returning the nodeset (in your case generated by "$('select')") so that the method can be integrated into a chain.

Answer (score 1):

To test for a value:

```
var haveTopic = $("select option[value='not here']").length != 0
```

**Edit**

To test for text:

```
var haveTopic = $.inArray('Not Here',$("select").text().replace(/ /g,'').split("\n")) != -1
```

Comment: This would find the value of "not here" - OP is looking for the text contents of "not here".

Comment: @Mark: Yes @Frank DeRosa is right. I've corrected the question now, sorry about that.

Comment: @Alex: I re-wrote it to test for text, see above.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at how .filter(fn) is implemented, however you could use it as a solution.

```
$.fn.hasOptionWithText = function(text) {

    var options = $("option", $(this)).filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() === text;
    });

    return options.length > 0;
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    var hasNotHere = $("select").hasOptionWithText('Not Here');
    var hasGeneral = $("select").hasOptionWithText('General');

    alert(hasNotHere + ' ' + hasGeneral);
});
```